# Trouble understanding loading json with promises express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my nodeJs app I create a post request;

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(80, () => console.log('Listening at 80'));

var movies = require("G:/path/to/json/movienames.json");
app.use(express.json({ limit: '1mb'}));

app.post('/movies', (request, response) => {
    console.log('I got a request!');
    console.log(request.body);
    response.json(
        movies
    );
});
```

Now in my Javascript file i need to receive the promise and get the data with .then with a function call to convert it to json. Then it sends the data. I guess?

```
const postMovieLoad = {"Movies has been loaded": "True"};
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postMovieLoad)
};
moviesJson = fetch('/movies', {
    method: "POST", // "GET/POST"
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postMovieLoad)
})
.then(moviesJson => moviesJson.json())
.then(moviesJson => {
  Json = {//Json copied directly from file};
  console.log(Json === moviesJson); //logs false
  console.log(Json); // logs {movies: Array(193)}
  console.log(moviesJson); // logs {movies: Array(193)}
  console.log(typeof Json, typeof moviesJson); //logs object object
}).catch(error => console.error('Error', error))
```

I fetch the promise. The syntax is confusing me alot here. I'm a little unsure about the .then function stringed together. I think its like a handshake between the server and the client.

What is really stumping me though, is why the file has been modified and why? Both are json objects, both have the same contents. I just want to get the json object to be assigned to a variable client side from server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do that (a === b), you are comparing that a and b are the same object, that is, the same reference in memory, since the objects in javascript are references, in your case a and b do not have the same memory address, then you will not be able to do it that way JSON.stringify (a) == JSON.stringify (b) could help, you could add a trim to be safer since there you convert it to string and the comparison is not by reference, its by characters length and order

Comment: Thanks, but i still can't get this json object outside the scope of the .then function. I get a Error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object Error, when passing a function parameter. And a var is never read when assigning it.

How do I use this object client side?

Comment: I think code is missing there. If I understand you well what happens is that the promise code does not block, then you in effect make the call to the server but check the Json variable before the server responds, therefore at that moment it is null

Comment: That makes sense, so your saying to use await? I just want to assign the contents of the json object to a variable and pass it to a function, that isn't inside .then()

Comment: The function that isn't inside then(), but you can call it inside then 
    .then(json => {
        yourFunction(json);
    });

Comment: Yeh, I have gotten that working... I'm starting to think this isn't my issue. I think my issue is client side jquery.

It's weird that outside .then jquery works fine for rendering dom elements, but inside .then jquery doesn't work.